# basic javascript form validation - validate same input types with same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function, validation

I have always used jQuery validate() for forms, but have run into a problem recently after an upgrade to our XMPie software (we do targeted communications).

The new version of XMPie requires jQuery 1.10.2 which is a version not supported by validate(), so I'm doing the validation manually.

I can easily validate by writing a separate function for each input, but it means re-writing at least some of the code to target a specific input name or id for example.

What I'm wondering is why can't I write a generic function for a specific input type (for example a simple text field) and let the input call the function on focusout(), passing itself as a parameter?

If I've got two text inputs, "fullName" and "userName" why can't I use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inputName = "";
    var inputValue = "";
    var inputAlert = "";
    $("input").focusout(function () {
        inputIdentify(this);
        console.log(inputName);
        inputGetValue(this);
        console.log(inputValue);
        if (this.type == "text") {
            console.log("YES");
            textValidate(inputName, inputValue);
        }
    });

    function inputIdentify(theInput) {
        inputName = theInput["name"];
        console.log(inputName);
        return inputName;
    }

    function inputGetValue(theInput) {
        inputValue = theInput["value"];
        return inputValue;
    }

    function textValidate(theInput, inputValue) {
        console.log(theInput,inputValue);
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
        if (inputValue.match(letters)) {
            $(theInput).addClass("correct");
            return true;
        } else {
            $(theInput).removeClass("correct");
            $(theInput).addClass("incorrect");

            // alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');
            $(inputName).focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

to remove and add simple css classes (coloured border) to indicate the problem fields?

Thanks and regards,

Malcolm

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Thanks for looking - yes the "correct" and "incorrect" classes are not being applied to the input field.

Comment: That's not what I meant by an error.

Comment: Can you add the HTML and CSS and make this an executable stack snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the correct arguments to `textValidate()`. You're passing `inputName` as the `theInput`, but `textValidate()` uses `$(theInput)` to access the input element. You should pass `this` as that argument:

```
textValidate(this, inputValue);
```

Also, your use of global variables is poor design. Since `inputIdentify()` and `inputGetValue()` return values, you should assign the returned value to local variables, instead of having those functions set global variables.

```
   $("input").focusout(function () {
        var inputName = inputIdentify(this);
        console.log(inputName);
        var inputValue = inputGetValue(this);
        console.log(inputValue);
        if (this.type == "text") {
            console.log("YES");
            textValidate(this, inputValue);
        }
    });

    function inputIdentify(theInput) {
        var inputName = theInput["name"];
        console.log(inputName);
        return inputName;
    }

    function inputGetValue(theInput) {
        var inputValue = theInput["value"];
        return inputValue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I know it's pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I know it's pretty basic stuff. You're right about using `this` as an argument for `textValidate()` - that was dumb. And you're right about the global variables - except for `inputValue`. When I remove that one, and `console.log(inputValue)` right after the call to `inputGetValue()`, the variable is blank.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't assign to the variable when you called it. I've updated the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you Barmar - that is great and just what I need. Now that I see it, declaring the variable as part of the function call is so obvious. I'm just learning ...